# Attempting to push object into array of objects turns it into an integer

Tags: javascript

I need to create a new object and push it into an array of objects. When i try the code below it instead results in an integer which is the value of the array length.

```
const newThing = Object.assign(
            {},
            {
                __typename: 'Group',
                id: groupId,
            },
        );

        // userGroups is an array of strings eg ['1', '2']

        const newUserGroups = userGroups
            .map(item => {
                return Object.assign({}, { __typename: 'Group' }, { id: item });
            })
            .push( newThing );

        console.log(newUserGroups);
```

Comment: `push` returns the new length of the array.

Comment: Yes, and there must be a dupe of this.

Comment: use `concat` instead.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use [`Array#concat`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/concat), because [`Array#push`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/push) returns the new length of the array and concat returns a new array.

```
const newUserGroups = userGroups
        .map(item => {
            return Object.assign({}, { __typename: 'Group' }, { id: item });
        })
        .concat(newThing);
```

Answer (score 0):

You are miss-implementing the chaining.

currently your chain is like this:

`x = array.map().push()`

so  `x` will get the returned value of the last chained method (`push`)

And `push` return the length of the array, not the array itself.

See https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/push

Remove the chain and it will be ok:

```js
const newThing = Object.assign({}, {
  __typename: 'Group',
  id: 'groupId',
}, );

// userGroups is an array of strings eg ['1', '2']
const userGroups = ['1', '2'];

const newUserGroups = userGroups
  .map(item => {
    return Object.assign({}, {
      __typename: 'Group'
    }, {
      id: item
    });
  });
  
newUserGroups.push(newThing);

console.log(newUserGroups);
```